# Add 7 days to a timestamp date mysql

Tags: mysql

I am setting up a trigger which reads a timestamp column and adds 7 days to it and then puts the newly calculated date into another column in the same table. The timestamp column is called date_requested and the new column is called `return_date`. Here is my code so far. 
Thanks in advance

```
DELIMITER //

    CREATE TRIGGER external_requests_date_trig BEFORE INSERT ON external_requests
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    SET NEW.return_date = DATE_ADD(NEW.date_requested, INTERVAL 7 DAY);

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert timestamp into a database + 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504395/insert-timestamp-into-a-database-7-days)

Comment: Try to use trigger with `AFTER` may make any changes

Comment: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger This error appears when I change before insert to after insert

Comment: 1) what's wrong with your code? 2) why don't you use a generated column or view instead of a trigger?

Comment: This code is bringing back null values when the calculation is complete. This code is working fine for a date column in a different table but the difference is that the problem i am having now is it is not adding days to a timestamp

Comment: @user11271599 - can you show example data which cause the NULL values? Also show the `CREATE TABLE` of `external_requests`.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch CREATE TABLE external_requests (
 request_id int(100) not null auto_increment,
 book_id int(100) not null, 
 date_requested TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 return_date date not null,
 library_name varchar(100) not null,
 library_phone int(20) not null,
 primary key (request_id),
 CONSTRAINT FK_external_requests_1 FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
    REFERENCES books(book_id)
  
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @SebastianBrosch return_date column showing 0000-00-00

Comment: can't reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce711755fab9dbcc8c0e9397770bcc6c

Comment: @SebastianBrosch cheers man that worked for me. The Now() syntax was the part I was missing