# How can i add 4 more days to the current_timestamp on mysql

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

This is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Stoc URGENT` (
  `ID Produs` INT NOT NULL,
  `Data livrari` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  -- other columns
```

How can I add 4 days to current_timestamp?

Comment: That's an incomplete statement. Consider adding a generated column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert timestamp into a database + 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504395/insert-timestamp-into-a-database-7-days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
`Data livrari` DATETIME ON UPDATE DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Comment: Is not working it says "data_add is not valabil at this position"

Comment: @CristianOctavianManea where do you see `data_add`?

Comment: in here  `Data livrari` DATETIME ON UPDATE DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 4 DAY), i put in the creation of the table

Comment: It's `datE_add` not `datA_add`: `E` not `A`. Rather than reading and mis-typing, I recommend copy-pasting to avoid introducing errors to working code.

Comment: yess i did that but is showing the same message

Comment: Are you actually using MySQL?

Comment: Yes MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE